# Replace values in DLL and rewrite it

Tags: c#

I have a `Native` dll which is added to a C# application's embedded resources, what i want to do here is to replace certain strings inside that dll and export a  new dll with the new values...

Here is what i tried so far.

```
public static byte[] Replace(byte[] src, string replace, string replacewith)
{
    string sourceHex = BitConverter.ToString(src).Replace("-", "");
    string replaceHex = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(replace)).Replace("-", "");
    string replaceWithHex = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(replacewith)).Replace("-", "");
    sourceHex = sourceHex.Replace(replaceHex, replaceWithHex);
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sourceHex);
}
```

Result -> Corrupted Dll with increase disk space.

Comment: How do you know that the byte '-', for example, is not part of any op-code in the DLL? You seem to think that the entire file is one big string, which will dynamically resize itself for the convenience of your string replacements. That's an incorrect model of how DLL's are constructed.

Comment: the - is a normal result of Bitconvert.ToString @PieterGeerkens

Comment: I think you're underestimating what is required to make this work, its not trivial and are better off looking at assembly reverse engineering tools.

Comment: Use jetbrains dotpeek. Extract code, change it, build it and use it.

Comment: @ATP i want to do this on the fly, at runtime so i can't use this solution...

Comment: @ATP its a native DLL

Comment: This may probably help https://static1.squarespace.com/static/556340ece4b0869396f21099/t/55849347e4b0abb5bb698dd5/1434751815624/uninformed_v1a7.pdf